# Sessions with express and socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm fairly new and am trying to set up a simple image sharing site with account creation. I'm using socket.io and express and have a login created.

I've been told you should never identify users with socket ids, which I now realize is difficult if not impossible

I'm having trouble implementing the user information. I've been looking into the client-sessions packages, but I've hit a wall. I'm not trying to have someone else write all my code for me, but it would be appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: So, do your users need to register or something like that so that you store their info?

Comment: yes, they register and their login information is passed into a mongodb and stored. I then redirect the user to a login page where they submit their  information. Logging in takes you to a profile page. I'm stuck when it comes to passing the user information around.

Comment: Are you using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) to communicate with MongoDB?

Comment: yep, mongoose all the way

Comment: I have used once [passport](http://passportjs.org/) for registering, etc... I don't know if you would like to use it or if it even would help you in your case... You need somehow to store the ID of the current user in the view, for example as an attribute of a HTML element, then you can gather info about the current logged user since you know its ID, but I am not even sure if this is your problem...

Comment: My issue initially is that I thought a client used the same socket until the user closed their browser. My initial plan was to identify users by socket, but that fell through, obviously. My inexperience with node isn't helping me here. Thanks for your suggestions anyways.

Comment: I have used socket.io only for updating in real time changes in all browsers, etc, so I am not so familiar with it actually, and what you could even do more than what I did when I used it.